# Order of elements in a coset

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $b \in G$. Suppose $\operatorname{ord(G)} = 2p, \operatorname{ord(H)} = p, \operatorname{ord(b) = 2}$, then $bH$ is a left coset of $H$ that contains $p$ elements of order $2$.

Granted it's true(is it?), $H$ contains $p$ elements of order $p$ so $bH$ contains $p$ elements, but how does $b$ affect $H$ in such a way that $bH$ contains elements of order $2$, not $p$? $b^2h^p = e$, how do we get $\operatorname{ord(bh) = 2}$?

Comment: shouldn't $p$ be a prime?

Comment: @AnuragA, yes, $p \neq 2.$ If you're interested, here's the [proof](https://s21.postimg.org/zc3z9yil3/answer.png) that inspired this question. Here's the [claim](https://s28.postimg.org/ue8yenhnh/Question.png).

Comment: @user330613 I don't get it: what you want is proved very nicely in the link you sent. Is there anything you don't understand there or maybe you have *another* question? What's proved there is that $\;b\notin H\implies ord(b)=2\;$ , and since $\;bh\notin H\;$ for all $\;h\in H\;$ , then **all** the elements of the coset $\;bH\;$ have order two.

Comment: @Joanpemo, what are some elements of $bH$? Maybe I don't understand what $bH$ is supposed to be like?

Comment: @user330613 By definition $$bH:=\{bh\;:\;\;h\in H\}$$ and observe that none of these elements is in $\;H\;$, lest $\;b\in H\;$ ...

Comment: @Joanpemo, it makes sense that $H$ has $p$ elements of order $p$ as $b \not \in H.$ I was just wondering why when we multiply $h$ with $b$, the order of $b$ "overpowers". I guess I just have to think a bit more :)

Comment: In the link you sent it is proved that **any** element not in $\;H\;$ has order two. Since all the elements in $\;bH\;$ *are not in* $\;H\;$ , they all have order two. I don't understand what you mean by "overpowers" and etc.

Comment: @Joanpemo, ok now I see. "**Any** element not in $H$" is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks and have a nice day.